# Lebesgue measure of difference of open set and borel set less that epsilon

Tags: lebesgue-measure, borel-sets

Proposition 4.14(1) from Bass, http://bass.math.uconn.edu/3rd.pdf:

> Suppose $A \subseteq [0, 1]$ is a Borel measurable set.
>   Let $m$ be Lebesgue measure.
>   (1) Given $\varepsilon>0$, there exists an open set $G$ so that $m(G−A) < \varepsilon$
>   and $A \subseteq G$.

My question is about the first sentence in the proof:

> There exists a set of the form $E =\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty (a_j , b_j]$ such that $A ⊂ E$ and $m(E − A) < \varepsilon/2$.

What is the argument that such a union exists? The problem is to assure that $m(E − A) < \varepsilon/2$.
I see some connection with the definition of Lebesgue outer measure
or perhaps I should prove the sentence

> Every set in the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$ is $\mu^*$-measurable.

that I have found in my notes (without proof).

Comment: It simply follows from the definition of outer measure. Do you know that definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition of outer measure, you have
$$m(A)= \inf \left\{ \sum_j (b_j-a_j) : A \subseteq \bigcup_j (a_j, b_j] \right\}$$
Fix $\varepsilon >0$. Then there exists a countable union of intervals
$$E = \bigcup_j (a_j, b_j] \supseteq A$$
such that
$$m(E)-m(A) < \varepsilon/2$$
Hence, since both $A$ and $E$ are Borel measurable, you have
$$m(E-A) = m(E)-m(A) < \varepsilon/2$$
This proves the first claim.

To prove the second claim, i.e. every Borel is measurable, it is enough to prove that every open bounded interval $(a,b)$ is measurable.
A proof of this can be found at [Prove that any interval is measurable.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2328599/prove-that-any-interval-is-measurable) , for example.

Then, since measurable sets form a sigma-algebra, countable unions of open intervals (read all open sets) are measurable. Again, since Borel sets are the sigma-algebra generated by open sets, it is contained in the sigma-algebra of all measurable sets.

Comment: The main point I missed was the connection between an abstract outer measure and the fact that the Lebesgue-Stieltjes measures (so the L. measure) use half-open intervals. Thank you also for the other points.